# Numpy array from int to float

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I have this code to extract some data from a csv. I can extract the data with no problem but I would like to change the numpy array from a int to a float. I know that the argument to do that is `dtype=np.float32` but I keep having an error message when I do include this argument:
This is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
rainfall=pd.read_csv('Seattle2014.csv')['PRCP'].values
inches=rainfall / 254
inches.shape

#...

rainy=(inches >0)
summer=(np.arange(365)-172<90) &(np.arange(365)-172>0)
print ("Mediam precipitation on rainy days in 2014  (inches):       ",np.median(inches[rainy]))
print ("Mediam precipitation on summer days in 2014 (inches):       ",np.median(inches[summer]))
print ("Maximum precipitation on summer days in 2014 (inches):      ",np.max(inches[summer]))
print ("Median precipitation on non-summer days in 2014 (inches):  ",np.median(inches[rainy & ~summer]))
```

This is the code with the argument:

```
rainy=(inches >0)
summer=(np.arange(365)-172<90) &(np.arange(365)-172>0)
print ("Mediam precipitation on rainy days in 2014  (inches):       ",np.median(inches[rainy], dtype=float))
```

And I do get this error message:

```
TypeErrorTraceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-136-29b7a435cc0e> in <module>()
      1 rainy=(inches >0)
      2 summer=(np.arange(365)-172<90) &(np.arange(365)-172>0)
----> 3 print ("Mediam precipitation on rainy days in 2014  (inches):       ",np.median(inches[rainy], dtype=float))
      4 print ("Mediam precipitation on summer days in 2014 (inches):       ",np.median(inches[summer]))
      5 print ("Maximum precipitation on summer days in 2014 (inches):      ",np.max(inches[summer]))

TypeError: median() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dtype'
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: remove the dtype argument, obviously

Comment: "I know that the argument to do that is dtype=np.float32" no---that's the argument to specify the type when you *create* the array.  The median function has no such keyword argument, as the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.median.html) show. It's a single element anyways right? Just use `float(...)`.

Comment: Also it's unclear why you're using numpy to do the manipulations since you originally read in a dataframe from pandas. Just use the `.median()` and `.max()` and so on methods on the dataframe? You can print whatever representation you choose regardless.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds I am trying to follow an exercise in "Python Data Science Handbook", the exercise starts around page 70 and goes to 74-76. The csv file is a download from the github page related to the book. In the book, the solution are presented as float but when I do it I get integers. I must be something missing or the csv file used for the book is different than the one in github.

Comment: How about  just changing the rainfall data to float directly: `rainfall=pd.read_csv('Seattle2014.csv')['PRCP'].values.astype(np.float)`

Comment: @Mstaino. Thanks. That has work perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

[`numpy.median()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.median.html) has no argument `dtype`. This is its output behaviour:

> **RETURNS:** median : *ndarray*
>
> A new array holding the result (unless *out* is specified, in which case that array is returned instead). **If the input contains integers, or floats of smaller precision than 64, then the output data-type is float64. Otherwise, the output data-type is the same as that of the input.**